# Installing PyAutoGui on multiple versions of Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyautogui

I, as it will soon be obvious, am a total newb when it comes to Python.

I am running python version 3.5 on Windows 10, 64 bit.

I installed the PyAutoGui module for a small project I am working on. At first, everything worked perfectly. But now it appears that PyAutoGui is crashing when it clicks. I suspect that it's because PyAutoGui is only intended for use up to Python 3.4.

In order to rectify this, I downloaded Python 3.4. Unfortunately, however, when I try to install PyAutoGui (using pip install pyautogui), it tells me that it's already been installed because it sees it in the Python 3.5 folder.

My question is this: How do I install PyAutoGui in Python 3.4 with it already installed in Python 3.5?
**Assume that I know virtually nothing about how to install a module manually without using pip**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple versions of Python installed you need to find your versions and rename them and their Pips.

In windows the path is, `C:\\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3x-32`. The x should be replaced with the Python version and `USERNAME` with your username. On Mac it's located in `/usr/local/bin/python`. On Linux it should be in `/usr/bin/python`. The location might vary depending on OS and Python version.

Rename the files `python.exe`/`python` and `pip.exe`/`pip` so that each file is different. I named mine `python35.exe`, `python2.exe` and `python.exe`(for 3.5, 2.7 and 3.6).

Now when you execute your pip command use, `pip34 install pyautogui` or whatever you named the file.

Or if you *really* want to you can go the painful way of renaming all the path variables, but I won't explain that here.